# Can I open a Sencha panel/popup on top of an InAppBrowser Window in the loadstart event listener?

Tags: sencha-touch-2, inappbrowser

Can I open a Sencha Touch panel/popup on top of an InAppBrowser Window in
the loadstart event listener??

Currently the Popup Window is opening behind the InAppBrowser.

***Example:***

```
IabRef.addEventListener('loadstart', function() {                                 
   loginPopup = me.getPopup();
   Ext.Viewport.add(loginPopup);
   loginPopup.show({type: 'slideIn', direction: 'right'});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.

The InAppBrowser is a new Activity which resides on top of yours.